# YII2 XML file upload wont validate

Tags: php, xml, validation, yii, yii2

I'm making a file upload controller to upload a bunch of XML files to a server.

However, some XML files don't have the `<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">` tag and Yii validator fails to upload these files.

```
public $xmlFiles;

public function rules() {
    return [
        [['xmlFiles'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'xml', 'maxFiles' => 20],
    ];
}

public function upload($path) {
    if (empty($path)) {
        return false;
    }

    FileHelper::createDirectory($path);

    if ($this->validate()) {
        foreach ($this->xmlFiles as $file) {
            $file->saveAs($path . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);
        }
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can I change my validation rule to allow this kind of files?

Answer (score 0):

You can always set `checkExtensionByMimeType` to `false` in your validation rule and see if it helps.

This one forces validator to not compare MIME type with file extension and thanks to this some files can pass (like plain text *.csv files or probably your *.xml files). Be aware that with this option user can send you any malicious file only by renaming its extension.

**Edit:**
You can set `mimeTypes` property in your rule to specific all the MIME types you want to be valid. In your case it might be something like:

```
['xmlFiles', 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'mimeTypes' => ['application/xml'], 'maxFiles' => 20],
```

With `extensions` property removed only MIME type is being checked.

It is possible though that in your case MIME type is just `text/plain` (you should check this first). You can set this here but it will allow all plain text files which is still better than allowing everything.

Comment: that is precisely what I'm trying to avoid